# handle on tab press event to add dynamic customize row in editable html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ckeditor

i just created a editable table and its default behaviour is when press tab on last table cell then add new row at last of table.

i want to handle this event key-press on dynamic row.

and one another issue is on tab cursor not blink on new table cell, when i type something else it work.

and also backspace not work to remove table cell.

i try this for handle key-down:

```
$(".table_desc tr").on('keydown', 'td', function(e) { 
    console.log("call keydown");
}
```

but this event call for only that table cell which are created on page load.

is there possible to blink cursor using css on press tab?
my ck-editor version is 4.3.2.

i think in latest version this issues solved but i want code for handle this in 4.3.2 version.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('keyup', '.table_desc tr td', function(e) {
    console.log("call keydown");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table_desc" border="1" contenteditable="true">
  <tr>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td>demo1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td>demo1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on('keyup', '.table_desc tr td', function(e) {
    console.log("call keydown");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table_desc" border="1" contenteditable="true">
  <tr>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td>demo1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td>demo1</td>
    <td>demo1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```